# Output format in Jena Fuseki server

Tags: format, jena, fuseki

Given this command:

```
prefix dm:  <http://one.example/>
SELECT ?pID
WHERE
{
 ?pID dm:hasDName "xxxvvvII" .
}
```

The arq engine outputs the following:

```
-------------------
| pID           |
===================
| dm:C002172      |
-------------------
```

The fuseki server outputs the following:

```
{
"head": {
"vars": [ "pID" ]
} ,
"results": {
"bindings": [
  {
    "pID": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://one.example/C002172" }
  }
 ]
}
}
```

First question: how can I make the Fuseki server output the result in a more readable way with out the all braces and other token?

Second question: how can I delete datasets from Fuseki server, There is no such option in the control panel and I searched online. But all I can find is this:
http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/soh.html

I tried these command in the terminal but they didn't actually work?

Answer (score 3):

1. Ask for format text/plain (content negotiation or ?output=text). Also CSV or TSV formats may be useful to you.
2. Re: deleting datasets. Not in the current release.  You can empty them though, either each graph as in SOH DELETE or PUT of empty content, or PUT empty content (e.g. N-Quads) to http://localhost:3030/dataset/ using curl, wget.

Comment: Thanks @AndyS but when I try s-put or s-delete, I get command not found error. Ruby is installed in my system.

Comment: They are in the Fuseki distribution.  Make surethey are accessible to the command path and marked executable for your system.  You may also need to fix how it finds ruby.

Comment: Can you please let me know of how I check if they are accessible to the command path and marked executable for your system?

Comment: That is basic OS setup.

Comment: Can you please let me know how I can check if they are accessible to the command path and marked executable for my system?